# Logging EF Core sql statements with Serilog

Tags: serilog, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1, ef-core-2.2

How can I get EF Core (3.0) logging as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging) with Serilog ?

In particular I need the sql statement of an IQueryable ?

Is this possible with Serilog ?